# BLUR airdrop claim explained - embedding a proof into a transaction

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, nft

Recently, I saw that Blur had a twitter dependent airdrop. So basically you had to tweet and then you would get the option to claim tokens. I went to analyze the code, but it is overwhelming for me.

This is the claim function:

```
function claim(
        address account,
        uint256 amount,
        bytes32[] memory proof
    ) external {
        bytes32 leaf = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(account, amount));
        require(!claimed[leaf], "Airdrop already claimed");
        MerkleVerifier._verifyProof(leaf, merkleRoot, proof);
        claimed[leaf] = true;

        require(IERC20(token).transfer(account, amount), "Transfer failed");

        emit Claimed(account, amount);
    }
```

This is the Merklee Verifier:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

/**
 * @title MerkleVerifier
 * @dev Utility functions for Merkle tree computations
 */
library MerkleVerifier {
    error InvalidProof();

    /**
     * @dev Verify the merkle proof
     * @param leaf leaf
     * @param root root
     * @param proof proof
     */
    function _verifyProof(
        bytes32 leaf,
        bytes32 root,
        bytes32[] memory proof
    ) public pure {
        bytes32 computedRoot = _computeRoot(leaf, proof);
        if (computedRoot != root) {
            revert InvalidProof();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev Compute the merkle root
     * @param leaf leaf
     * @param proof proof
     */
    function _computeRoot(
        bytes32 leaf,
        bytes32[] memory proof
    ) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        bytes32 computedHash = leaf;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < proof.length; i++) {
            bytes32 proofElement = proof[i];
            computedHash = _hashPair(computedHash, proofElement);
        }
        return computedHash;
    }

    function _hashPair(bytes32 a, bytes32 b) private pure returns (bytes32) {
        return a < b ? _efficientHash(a, b) : _efficientHash(b, a);
    }

    function _efficientHash(
        bytes32 a,
        bytes32 b
    ) private pure returns (bytes32 value) {
        assembly {
            mstore(0x00, a)
            mstore(0x20, b)
            value := keccak256(0x00, 0x40)
        }
    }
}
```

My theory is that each time a user tweets, the website recognizes this and embeds a special proof in the transaction, which is then computed with the amount and address and finally verified with the root proof(the only owner function). What I don't understand is why can't this system be cheated? Can't we just copy one of the proofs into the transaction and avoid the twitter verfication?

And most importantly: How is the proof created? How can the contract follow twitter(there is no oracle to my knowledge)?

Answer (score 3):

> *why can't this system be cheated? Can't we just copy one of the proofs into the transaction and avoid the twitter verfication?*

In this specific case, if you pass someone else's `proof` and your `account`, the claim fails.

```
bytes32 leaf = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(account, amount));
```

The resulting `leaf` value is different for each input. So an eligible address would result in leaf `0x12` while your address would result in leaf value `0x34`.

Now, the `_verifyProof()` function validates if the **combination** of `leaf` and `proof` leads to the expected `root`.

```
bytes32 computedHash = leaf;
// ...
computedHash = _hashPair(computedHash, proofElement);
```

Since your `leaf` is different from the eligible (while the `proof` is the same), the combination leads to a different `root` value, and this condition reverts:

```
if (computedRoot != root) {
    revert InvalidProof();
}
```

---

And if you pass their `proof` and their `account` as well, then you simply claim the airdrop to their address - not to yours:

```
// sends tokens to `account` - not to `msg.sender`
IERC20(token).transfer(account, amount)
```

Comment: How is the generated? There is no connection between twitter and the contract.

Comment: @NFT_king It's usually generated using offchain methods. I'm not familiar with this specific case - but generally, you can create a list of eligible addresses (from users that fit certain criteria such as 1. tweet, 2. join a youtube channel, 3. like a post, 4. pass their crypto address along with social media handles for automated verification to an online form) and build a merkle tree using this input. Then the root of this tree is passed to the contract and verified onchain.

Comment: The problem with this is that the list should upgraded each time a user tweets(changing the proof) which is inefficient.

Comment: @NFT_king Yes that would be inefficient. Usually there's a time period where the addresses are collected - and only after this period ends (and the list cannot grow anymore), the root is calculated and passed to the contract... Or another workaround might be batching. So the root value in contract is not updated instantly but only after a certain period of time or after some number of users signed up.